# HTML Menu items are displaying gaps

Tags: html, css, menu

I have two levels of menus.  I'm trying to give my menu's a different look; I'm removing the background color from the top level menu items.  To do this I altered the CSS class ".nav li".  I commented out the "background-color" property.  However, that gives me a problem with the sub-menu items.  When I hover my cursor over one of the upper menu items and the corresponding sub-menu items appear, they are displaying with a 5px gap in between them.  That comes from the "margin" property in the ".nav li a" class.  If I reduce the value of the margin property to anything less than 5, I can't select any sub-menu item.  They sub-menu items disappear when I hover over them.

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  /* Needed for menu to float and center.  Explicit PX doesn't work */
  margin-left: -30px;
  /*To accommodate the difference between page width and menu */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* no underscores, etc. */
  text-align: center;
  /* needed for menu to float and center. */
  position: fixed;
  /* used to render menu bar fixed on top and not scroll up */
  /* ALSO ALLOWS MENUS TO STAY ON TOP OF SLIDESHOW*/
  top: 0;
  /* used to render menu bar on top */
  z-index: 1000;
  /* use z-index to render menu bar on top of everything, even the slideshow */
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* used to wrap text */
  position: relative;
  /* to enable items to "drop down" */
  float: none;
  /* needed for menu to float with risized window */
  /*background-color: #BDB76B; */
  /* menu background color */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav li:hover {
  /* highlights current hovered list item when hovering over the parent menu */
  background-color: #D1CA88;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* used to wrap text */
  margin: 5px 0;
  /*space between menu elements Top, Right, Bottom, Left */
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  /* this is the standard width of the menu items */
  line-height: 15px;
  /* this is the text height of the menu items */
  color: #000000;
  /* list item font color 000=black, FFF=white*/
}

.nav li a:hover {
  /* highlights hovered item of the parent menu */
  background-color: #D1CA88;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/contact_us.html">Staff</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact_us.html#council">Council</a></li>
      <li><a href="/registration/input1.php">Registration Form</a></li>
      <li><a href="/map_and_directions.html">Map and Directions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I remove the background-color property for the top level items and still have no gaps display in the background for the sub-menu items and keep the sub-menu items displaying while I hover over them?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you mean. Didn't fully understand the goal.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    /* Needed for menu to float and center.  Explicit PX doesn't work */
    margin-left: -30px;
    /*To accommodate the difference between page width and menu */
    list-style-type: none;
    /* no underscores, etc. */
    text-align: center;
    /* needed for menu to float and center. */
    position: fixed;
    /* used to render menu bar fixed on top and not scroll up */
    /* ALSO ALLOWS MENUS TO STAY ON TOP OF SLIDESHOW*/
    top: 0;
    /* used to render menu bar on top */
    z-index: 1000;
    /* use z-index to render menu bar on top of everything, even the slideshow */
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* used to wrap text */
    position: relative;
    /* to enable items to "drop down" */
    float: none;
    /* needed for menu to float with risized window */
    /*background-color: #BDB76B; */
    /* menu background color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
.target:hover {
    /* highlights current hovered list item when hovering over the parent menu */
    background-color: #D1CA88;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    /* used to wrap text */
    margin: 5px 0;
    /*space between menu elements Top, Right, Bottom, Left */
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    /* this is the standard width of the menu items */
    line-height: 15px;
    /* this is the text height of the menu items */
    color: #000000;
    /* list item font color 000=black, FFF=white*/
  }
  
  .nav li a:hover {
    /* highlights hovered item of the parent menu */
    background-color: #D1CA88;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: blue;
    /* font-size: 18px; */
  }
```

```html
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="target"><a href="/contact_us.html">Staff</a></li>
        <li class="target"><a href="/contact_us.html#council">Council</a></li>
        <li class="target"><a href="/registration/input1.php">Registration Form</a></li>
        <li class="target"><a href="/map_and_directions.html">Map and Directions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Brandon.  I moved the CSS comments to a separate line, just as you did, but that didn't alter anything.  The goal is to have the sub menu items (Staff, Council, Registration Form, Map and Directions) display without gaps between them and be able to hover over all four choices and select one of them.  If I change the "margin" property of the "nav li a" class from "margin: 5px 0;" to "margin: 1px 0;" I can't select any of the four sub-menu items

Comment: @user3138025 you must have more going on then thats interfering. if you view my snippet it's all clickable while being hovered. Even if i change the margin, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hello Again Brandon.  If I run that HTML code in Chrome or Edge I get the problem exactly as I described it.

Comment: That's odd because i'm running it in chrome. Is this all the code you have?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link href="CSS/SaintSusannaOrg_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

Comment: I made a test page and added the above before the HTML I posted earler.  Obviously I end the test page with </html>

Comment: Try adding the viewport. ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for all your help.  I really couldn't resolve the "Margin: 5px 0;" thing, so I took another approach.  I re-added the "background-color" property of the "nav li" class, but I made the color the same as the page body.  It gave me the results I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3138025 cool, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the exact selector by using a specific CSS selector sign.
For example: .nav > li (use greater than sign to select the exact next element).

You can read this article ~ [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)